# Display Network Encryption Type in Tshark?

Tags: encryption, wireshark, tshark, wifi

I've been using tshark to gather some basic information on networks near where I live. I've got tshark to display the bssid, ssid, and rssi but I was wondering if there was also a way to display the networks encryption type as well. I'm using the following command:

```
tshark -i wlan1mon -l -T fields -e wlan.bssid -e wlan.ssid -e radiotap.dbm_antsignal -Y 'wlan.ssid' | grep -v "ff:ff:ff"
```

and this is and example of the output I get:

```
00:11:22:33:44:55   Bell Wireless    -74,-74
66:77:88:99:00:22   Dlink            -83,-83
33:44:55:66:77:88   NetflixNChill    -68,-83
```

Ideally I'd want the output to look more like this:

```
00:11:22:33:44:55   Bell Wireless   WPA  -74,-74
66:77:88:99:00:22   Dlink           WPA2 -83,-83
33:44:55:66:77:88   NetflixNChill   Open -68,-83
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `-e wlan.rsn.pcs.type` and `-e wlan.rsn.gcs.type` are what you're looking for?  Those are for the *Pairwise Cipher Suite type"* and *"Group Cipher Suite type"*, respectively.

In case those aren't the fields you're interested in, or in case you want to include additional fields, you can find a complete list of display filters, including wlan filters, online at the Wireshark [Display Filter Reference](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/) page.

You can also get this information from:

- [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChUseViewMenuSection.html) itself via *"View -> Internals -> Supported Protocols -> ..."*, but unfortunately the sorting leaves much to be desired there.
- [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) using the `tshark -G fields` command, but this output isn't very user-friendly either.